# Drop down menu does not work if I enable bootstrap in my mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Very simply, I put a drop down menu on my navigation bar that is in my _layout.cshtml page. It has a few items and drops down when I click on it as expected. So far so good! But when I reference Bootstrap at the start of the page the menu will no longer drop down. Bootstrap is stepping on something that is breaking my drop down menu. It appears that Bootstrap is not competely compatable with MVC. Does anyone have any idea of what the fix should be? I have tried this in both Chrome and Firefox. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Bootstrap 4. Here is a sample of my _layout.cshtml page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Bootstrap Reference</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")    
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        @Html.ActionLink("BootStrap Practice", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
      </div>            
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">      
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>                         
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Add class `dropdown` in the `li` element.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Messages <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't solve the problem. Another developer told me that there are compatibility issues between MVC 5 and Bootstrap. I have searched for list of such issues, but have not found one. So far I have encountered issues with the html fieldset and drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by referencing Bootstrap near the end of the _Layout.cshtml page instead of the beginning of it. Not sure why that mattered, but I am new to Bootstrap and MVC, so in time I may have a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue wherin a bootstrap menu would not appear within a partially rendered view and adding the render tag at the end of the view fixed it.
In case I had a page that was partially rendering a view. The partial view was working perfectly on its own but once it was injected into another page the dropdown menu stopped working and there was zero errors or warnings in the console. Adding the Scripts.Render at the end of the partial view fixed it for some reason.